# Unable to load custom render models from external driver folder

Tags: virtual-reality, steam, quest, steamvr

I have created a custom render models for my controllers. I am able to load the render models from the default location : C:\Program Files (x86)\Steam\steamapps\common\SteamVR\resources\rendermodels.

But what I am trying is to load from a custom external driver folder from where alvr driver is getting loaded. I was able to load the input profile and icons from this path, but render models are not getting loaded.